# How to change the color of a button inside a sub-menu using vue js3 and element-plus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-plus

I've created a button in a sub-menu which when clicked should be able to change color

But whatever I do doesn't work.

This is the code for the button

I've added more code
[Link to Vue playground where you can find the code](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Also i would like to change the color of the active checkbox to this rgba(134, 154, 31, 1)

[This is how it is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdvEY.png) 
I tried using checkbox it didn't also work out.

Comment: Looks like a typo.  You didn't bind the object to the class, you just assigned a literal string.  It's the difference between `class=` and `:class=`. See [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style#binding-to-objects)

Comment: @yoduh I'm having another problem with a checkbox on my page. when it is clicked, it toggles on an changes color but when you click on it again to toggle it off it doesn't work

Comment: I don't have that problem when running the code you have shown so far (and fixing the class binding).  You will need to edit your question to include the minimal amount of code to reproduce.

Comment: [playground link](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: @yoduh I've added more code and the link to the playground is now in the question

Comment: I can appreciate wanting to simplify your actual code to only what's relevant, but it looks like you oversimplified to the point where any answer could not be applied to your actual code.  the playground shows no `<button>` elements.  no dynamic active class.  no styling.  it instead has radio inputs, which requires much more [specific CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#styling_radio_inputs) to style.  radio inputs also do not allow you to unselect an option by design.  if you must be able to unselect, use checkboxes or regular buttons.

Comment: @yoduh thanks for the suggestion. I've been able to resolve the problem. Please up vote my question so that my reputation can go up. Having a low reputation really limits my abilities on here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `:class` for this case. Example:

```html
<button 
  :class="isActive == true ? 'active' : ''" 
  @click="toggleActive"
> Active </button>
```

Comment: Thanks,  but can you check out the code in the playground for me . When I select select the checkbox, I can't unselect it. The link to the playground is in the question .

Comment: @coochie ok, it's easy to fix, you add name for 3 radio input is the same. Example: 3 input have name="content". It only select one thing with radio input have the same name.

Comment: @coochie you can read more in [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) .

Comment: @ Nguyễn Đức Gia Huy Thanks a lot ....what about changing the color of the button when selected. I've tried using inspect from the browser to get the exact class but it still doesn't change

Comment: @coochie do you use theme or template? try checking the color default of your theme/template and property to change it in document of theme/template.

Comment: I'm using template together with element-plus.

Comment: @coochie button in element-plus have `type` to change color with 6 color default, or you want to change different color, you use attribute `color`. Example by type: you use `:type="isActive == true ? 'default': 'primary'"` or by color: you use `:color="isActive == true ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF'"`.  Remember vote me best answer for your question. Thank you very much.

Comment: thanks for your help. I've marked your answer as accepted. But unfortunately I can't up vote it since my reputation is not yet up to 15. But you can upvote my question so that my reputation can also go up.  Thanks again for your help